# Calculate new release time for files

Tags: vbscript

We have some code that checks each incoming file against 3 different criteria before processing (Not a weekend, not after 6pm, not a holiday). This being said, I need to figure out how to have it check for a half hour now (bolded part). I have tried adding a `+ mRelease > 30` as well as `AND mRelease > 30` and both have failed. I have been altering this line

```
Do While (WeekDay(dRelease) = 1) OR (WeekDay(dRelease) = 7) OR (UBound(fHoliday) > -1) OR (tRelease >17)
```

Here is the code currently in place:

```
result = ""
dRelease = Now
tRelease = CStr(Hour(Now))
mRelease = CStr(Minute(Now))

aHoliday = Array("01/02/2017","01/16/2017","05/29/2017","07/04/2017","09/04/2017","10/09/2017","11/23/2017","11/24/2017","12/25/2017","12/26/2017")
dNow = CStr(DatePart("m",Date)) + "/" + CStr(DatePart("d",Date)) + "/" + CStr(DatePart("yyyy",Date))
dMonth = "0" + CStr(Month(dRelease))
dDay = "0" + CStr(Day(dRelease))
dYear = CStr(Year(dRelease))
fHoliday = Filter(aHoliday,Right(dMonth,2) + "/" + Right(dDay,2) + "/" + dYear)
'fHoliday = Filter(aHoliday,dNow)
'result = UBound(fHoliday)
'result = Left(dRelease,10)
'result = CStr(DatePart("m",Date)) + "/" + CStr(DatePart("d",Date)) + "/" + CStr(DatePart("yyyy",Date))
'While release date is a weekend, or release date is a holiday
Do While (WeekDay(dRelease) = 1) OR (WeekDay(dRelease) = 7) OR (UBound(fHoliday) > -1) OR (tRelease >17)
    'increase release date by 1
    dRelease = dRelease + 1
    'result = dRelease
    'check for holiday
    dMonth = "0" + CStr(Month(dRelease))
    dDay = "0" + CStr(Day(dRelease))
    dYear = CStr(Year(dRelease))
    'fHoliday = Filter(aHoliday,Left(dRelease,10))
    fHoliday = Filter(aHoliday,Right(dMonth,2) + "/" + Right(dDay,2) + "/" + dYear)
    tRelease = 00
Loop

'Format the release date to the Esker deferred date/time standard.
dMonth = "0" + CStr(Month(dRelease))
dDay = "0" + CStr(Day(dRelease))
dYear = CStr(Year(dRelease))
dtCurrent = Right(dMonth,2) + "/" + Right(dDay,2) + "/" + dYear

If dRelease > Now Then
    tRelease = "00:" + mRelease
Else
    tRelease = CStr(Hour(Now)) + ":" + CStr(Minute(Now))
End If

result = dtCurrent + " " + tRelease
```

Comment: VBScript and VB.NET are not the same. Which is it?

Comment: What exactly is the half hour supposed to accomplish? Is it that files can only come through for the first half of a particular hour?

Comment: Currently it check the time. If it is after the "tRelease >17" (I.E. 18:00) it will hold the file until after midnight. What I need now is to have it say, if it is after 16:30, hold the file.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
Do While (WeekDay(dRelease) = 1) OR (WeekDay(dRelease) = 7) OR (UBound(fHoliday) > -1) OR (tRelease >17)
  ...
Loop
```

into this:

```
If (WeekDay(dRelease) = 1) Or (WeekDay(dRelease) = 7) Or (UBound(fHoliday) > -1) Or (Time > CDate("16:30")) Then
  ...
End If
```

Comment: I receive this error:

    `Overflow: 'dRelease'
    @(22,3): Microsoft VBScript runtime error, complete script source is:`

Comment: The `Do While` should probably be an `If`. Otherwise I'd expect the script too increment `dRelease` until the date changes or the variable overflows. Whichever comes first.